# Phantomjs download clean html after javascript processing

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want create file and write clean html after javascript processing. How I can do this?

My code phantomjs:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
var fs = require('fs');

page.open(args[1], function(status){
    console.log("Status: " + page.content);
    if(status === "success") {

        fs.write('file.html', page.content, 'w');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Now it write html with not processed javascript. Help please save clean html with executed javascript. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the file contents look like now, and what you expect the contents to look like?

Comment: @AndrewLoh I have two tables in html, and have script jquery, which remove certain rows